# Comprobar el estado del firewall en Windows desde CMD

Tags: consola

Si para activar o desactivar el firewall se usa "netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state" on/off

Como saber si actualmente está en ON o en OFF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el comando que necesitas es:

```
netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state
```

Saludos.